# delete all site in list in phpliveregex.com

Tags: regex

i have a lot many list, and i want to delete all site

example:

```
http://www.example.com/events.php?id=
http://www.example.com/ngentot.php?id=
http://example.com/events1.php?id=
http://example.com/ngentot2.php?id=
```

after using phpliveregex.com show result

```
events.php?id=
ngentot.php?id=
events1.php?id=
ngentot2.php?id=
```

please give demo in http://www.phpliveregex.com

Comment: let this question be closed, the OP doesn't realize exactly what he wants

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex pattern:

```
[^/]+\?id=
```

**http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/jrN**

Comment: how to using preg_replace?

Comment: how the results appear in a tab preg_result

Comment: @NYARUU.com, to use `preg_replace` you should specify the `replacement` part

Comment: @RomanPerekhest What should I fill in the column replacement?

Comment: @NYARUU.com, are you kidding me? My help was a waste

Comment: why i want show the result in preg_replace , cuz i want to copy without row number http://prntscr.com/em4pv5